# Delphi enable and disable click through to form

Tags: delphi

I use `SetWindowLong()` to click through my form. I would like to reverse this process, but do not know how. I use the code below:

```
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_HWNDPARENT, GetDesktopWindow);
```

Comment: Why are you using `SetWindowLong()` to set the parent window? Why not use `SetParent()` instead?

Comment: why not have the same result

Answer (score 2):

To remove the transparent style:

```
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) and not WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
```